# Read the content of a file with Kafka producer - FileSource Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How to use Kafka producer to read the content of a file? The typical solution found here(pipe the file into the producer with `|`) looks dirty and ugly.

Comment: What format is the file in? CSV?

Comment: Just a plain text file. Any format, just not binary. The question is actually 
a Q&A; thanks for your time... I shall just mention it.

Comment: OK. Bear in mind the caveat on FileSourceConnector from the docs "It is not recommended for production use.". You might instead look at https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Comment: Definitely should be taken into consideration; what I need is a robust log file reader; any suggestion of alternatives? Do I have to implement another one? I just need to get lines in a file; I don't quite get why the doc says the file-source connector (I mean the script) is not for production.

Comment: Connect Distributed mode is recommended for production usage because offsets and configuration  are committed back to Kafka itself persistently. And unless your files exist on every distributed worker, it doesn't make sense to use distributed mode with the file source. Additionally, it's only a single file, so you might as well pipe it into the console utility. In any case, KafkaCat, Flume, Fluentd, or Filebeat are great alternatives. https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3):

I recently found a solution more decent than piping the content of a file into the producer shell, that is to use [FileSource Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html).

According to the link, FileSource Connector aims to solve exactly the use case of "reading the data of a file into producer", like examining the content of a log file and launches alert when `[ERROR]` or `[FATAL]` is encountered.

The full command is(suppose we are in the root folder of Kafka):

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties
```

Two properties file to configure:

- `config/connect-standalone.properties`
- `config/connect-file-source.properties`

The first one defines how to connect to standalone connector. It is like:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# These are defaults. This file just demonstrates how to override some settings.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
 key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified, but most users will
# always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never visible outside of Kafka Connect in this format.
 internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
 internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include
# any combination of:
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Note: symlinks will be followed to discover dependencies or plugins.
# Examples:
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
#plugin.path=
```

Quite straightforward. Only two things to pay attention to:

- `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092`: the Kafka bootstrap server
- `(internal.)key/value.converter.schemas.enable=false`: You must set them to `false` to parse string lines in the file.

The second file is simpler:

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/tmp/test.txt
topic=connect-test
```

- `file`: which file to read
- `topic`: create a topic to make consumer to listen for

If you want to consume the content with Storm, that is enough.

If, instead of reading a file, you want to write content from Kafka to a file, you use FileSink Connector. I haven't use it personally, but I guess it is likewise, but on the consumer side. The config file is `config/connect-file-sink.properties`.